# insert row at index path call scroll to top table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When i insert row at index path in uitableview, then my tableview scroll to top? Why?

```
let indexPathForCell = NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 1)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForCell], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

All code that is invoked during the addition of the cell

```
func buttonDidPressed(button: CheckMarkView) {
    let indexPathForCell = NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 1)
    buttonPressedTag = button.tag
    for checkMark in buttons {
        if checkMark.tag == buttonPressedTag {
            if buttonPressedTag == 4 {
                checkMark.show()
                checkMark.userInteractionEnabled = false
                cellWithCategories["Recomendation"]?.append("slideCell")

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForCell], withRowAnimation: .None)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
            checkMark.show()
        } else {
            if (tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathForCell) != nil) {
                cellWithCategories["Recomendation"]?.removeLast()
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForCell], withRowAnimation: .None)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
            checkMark.hide()
            checkMark.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

code for number of rows :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionKey = keysForSectionTableView[section]
    let numberOfRows = cellWithCategories[sectionKey]

    return (numberOfRows?.count)!
}
```

Comment: try `withRowAnimation: .Middle`

Comment: @sken3r.MI its doesn't work :(

Comment: maybe you have more code that reloads data

Comment: How did u solve this issue?? @nickheck

Comment: I have the same issue, and I found the solution for it. [The Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206030/prevent-table-view-to-scrolling-top-after-insertrows)

Comment: you can fix it as this Post
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206030/prevent-table-view-to-scrolling-top-after-insertrows)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any code that will make your table view scroll to top.
But you can try change animation to none. If doesn't work then there is must be some other code, thats causing this issue.

```
let indexPathForCell = NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 1)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathForCell], withRowAnimation: .None)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, the table still scroll to the top