# prevent table view to scrolling top after insertRows

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have viewController with tableView inside it.
this tableView has many sections and rows.
when I try to add a new row in the last section using 
TableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: r, section: sec)], with: .bottom)

tableView scrolls to top, and displays the first cell in the current section.

how to prevent tableView from scrolling to the top?

thanks

---

This my solution

When try to add cell, I use this code

```
self.didAddNewCell = true
    self.chatTableView.reloadData()
    self.scrollToBottom()
```

Then adding this code

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if self.didAddNewCell {

        self.didAddNewCell = false

        let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y:CGFloat(chatTableView.contentSize.height - self.chatTableView.bounds.size.height))

        scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)

    }

}
```

And this code for scrolling to bottom

```
func scrollToBottom() {

    let sections = self.chatTableView.numberOfSections

    if sections > 0 {

        let rows = self.chatTableView.numberOfRows(inSection: sections - 1)

        let last = IndexPath(row: rows - 1, section: sections - 1)

        self.chatTableView.scrollToRow(at: last, at: .none, animated: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling [tableView reloadData] ?  Anyway you can use [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES]; for scrolling to the newly added row

Comment: Hi @user3752049 sure I use scrollToRow...., but the problem was that when I have a big number of rows (ex 50 rows). so when inserting new rows the tableView will scroll to top then back to the end of the table, And this is not good UX. did you understand me?

Answer (score 1):

**Try THIS IN YOUR `scrollViewDidScroll` METHOD-:**

```
  CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y:CGFloat(scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height))      

    scrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
```

Comment: I think this isn't the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks. I update my code and add your code with some extra code. And it is working now. Thaks

Comment: Maybe you can share your solution? Or, if Tushar's answer is correct, accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

updating the @Tushar Sharma answer...

just put the following line in method `scrollViewDidScroll` in your `UITableView`...

`contentOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y:CGFloat(scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height))`

where the `contentOffset` is `CGPoint`...
declear the global variable of `contentOffset`..

`var contentOffset : CGPoint?`

and use `contentOffset` value written after the code which causes the `UITableView` to scroll to the top as follow...

`self.tableView.setContentOffset(self.contentOffset!, animated: false)`

in my case its was `self.tableView.reloadData()` because i append values in dataset at index 0